# Decomposition of finitely generated abelian group as direct sum of torsion part and torsion free part

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm solving some problems suggested by my professor and I'm stuck on one of them.

**Problem 1 (OK).** Let $G$ be a abelian $p$-group for a prime $p$ of $\exp(G) = p^a$ e $g \in G$ with $|g| = p^a$. Show that existe $H \leq G$ such that $G = H \oplus \langle g \rangle$.

**Problem 2 (OK).** Let $G$ be a group and $g,h \in G$ elements of order $m,n$ respectively. If
$\gcd(m,n) = 1$ and $gh = hg$, then the order of $gh$ is $mn$.

**Problem 3 (OK).** Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Show that there exists $n_1,...,n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$G \simeq C_{n_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus C_{n_k}$$
where $n_i | n_{i+1}$.

> **Problem 4.** Let $G$ be a finitely generated abelian groups. Then there are $V_1,...,V_s$ infinite cyclic subgroups and $U_1,...,U_r$ finite cyclic subgroups such that
> $$G \simeq U_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_r \oplus V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_s$$
> where $|U_i| = n_i$ and $n_i | n_{i+1}$.

I solved the problems 1 - 3. The problems 1 and 2 are independent and I used both to solve 3 by induction on $|G|$. But I'm stuck in 4-th problem. I presume that I can use 3 to solve it.

My first idea is to take $T(G)$ as the torsion subgroup of $G$, so $G/T(G)$ is torsion free and write $G = T(G) \oplus H$ where $H \leq G$ satisfies $H \simeq G/T(G)$. Then apply problem 3 on $T(G)$ and show that $G/T(G) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^n$. But I'm not sure how to follow this steps.

Comment: What would $U_i$ and $V_i$ would be for the group $G=Z_8\oplus Z_9$?

Comment: @uniquesolution since $\gcd(8,9) = 1$, we can write this group as $C_{8\cdot 9}$, right?

Comment: My point is that if $G$ is finite there will be no infinite groups $V_i$, so the question is not really well posed. You may as well assume $G$ is a finite group to begin with and ignore the infinite parts, since the intereting part of the problem is all in the finite part.

Comment: @uniquesolution I see, but since the previous problem deal with the finite case, I think we can assume for 4-th problem $G$ infinite.

Comment: So just use the basis theorem and apply problem 3 to the sum of the finite parts.